# Getting historical values of a cell or row from Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Is there cell level (preferably) or row level versioning in Redshift tables.

For eg. 
Table: Motor_Speed 
Columns:
Motor_Id, CurrentSpeed, updateTime

For every motor Id, CurrentSpeed is updated a few times during the day.

How can I get historical values from this table for CurrentSpeed for a Motor Id.

Essentially does Redshift support Cell or Row level versioning?

DynamoDB provides such cell level versioning, how can we do that in Redshift?

Additional Context: This is a data warehouse table and we need a way to look at how this table row data changed over a period of time.

Comment: You have to do it explicitly in Redshift.  It overwrites the data if you are using `update`.

Comment: Take a look into "slowly changing dimensions" as this may give you some ideas on how to approach your concern.  A starting point - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension